# Reading PDF from email using imap

Tags: python

I am trying to read PDF attachments from email. The attachment should be saved in the directory specified. I am using IMAP library for this task.

```py
user = "user mail id"
password = "password"

attachment_dir = 'My sys path'

def auth(user,password,imap_url):
    con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
    con.login(user,password)
    return con

def get_body(msg):
    if msg.is_multipart():
        return get_body(msg.get_payload(0))
    else:
        return msg.get_payload(None,True)

def get_attachments(msg):
    for part in msg.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype()=='multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue
        fileName = part.get_filename()

        if bool(fileName):
            filePath = os.path.join(attachment_dir, fileName)
            with open(filePath,'wb') as f:
                f.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))

def search(key,value,con):
    result, data  = con.search(None,key,'"{}"'.format(value))
    return data

def get_emails(result_bytes):
    msgs = []
    for num in result_bytes[0].split():
        typ, data = con.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        msgs.append(data)
    return msgs

con = auth(user,password,imap_url)
con.select('INBOX')

result, data = con.fetch(b'10','(RFC822)')
raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
get_attachments(raw)
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-11-008775746550>", line 46, in <module>
    raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I want the pdf attachment in the mail to be stored in my local system. should I change any decoding technique ?

Comment: From the `Traceback`, you're assuming `data` is a `list`, but it's not.

Comment: More specifically, `data` or `data[0]` is `None`. What is `result`?

Comment: that is my doubt @Trenton_M .. how do I read PDF files? is there any decoding methods to do it?

Comment: @MarkRansom actually this mail id I provided has only mail with PDF attachment (created one specifically for that). so it has to save all the PDF attachment from that..

Comment: You might try some of these [Python imaplib.IMAP4_SSL() Examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/2875/imaplib.IMAP4_SSL).  If this is something like gmail, some setting might have to be configured for this to work.  I don't know.